# Power Query with Additional Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query

I am using a power query to read rows indexes by an item number from one file I receive to one file I am maintaining. I need to add some columns that are editable by me (cell editing), in a way that when the query is refreshed, these values will remain in the same row, with the same item number (these columns are additional remarks, dates and categories I need to keep for each item).  I have tried to expand the table generated by the power query (dragging the bottom right corner) and adding some columns this was. However, when I refresh the query, if the items in the query change order, the values in the additional columns do not match with the loaded description anymore.  My current solution is having another sheet (table) with the item number and remarks, and merging the two queries into one sheet. I'd like to be able to it in one sheet with one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who was looking for an answer to the above question. I was able to do the exact functionality by using a self-referencing table in the Power Query and merging it with the new data.

Basically, you add a new query from table and you load it as a connection.
Then, edit you original query and merge the new table query to it.

Expand your "Remarks" columns.

Your remarks will be read before any query refresh and loaded with the new query.

Comment: I seem to have your same exact need, however I struggle to understand the steps you took. Could you please detail a little more the steps that you applied? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to remember this. I added a new table query to read the current excel table (which includes a the manually editable columns). The purpose of this query is to extract these manual columns with the row index or item number (which will be used to merge it to the first part of the table). The main data of the table is generated by another query that queries external files, so that stays the same, but you add a few steps at the end of it so that it merges with the query that has the manual entry columns.

Comment: So basically, what power query does is 1.Read your existing excel table, store the index and manual entry columns (remarks) remove the other columns. 2. Run the external data query and generate all the data columns, then merge the remarks/manual entry columns into the same query. 3. Write back the query over the table which it read from the excel sheet thus updating the data columns and preserving the manual entry columns